# Output column based on unique text template for each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

This is the dataframe I am working with :

```
|ID | type | product | date  | time | template_id | template                                |
| 1 |  A   |   xx    | 04/01 | 4pm  |   1         | Product {0} was sold on {1} at {2}.format(product,date,time) |
| 2 |  A   |   xx    | 05/01 | 6pm  |   1         | Product {0} was sold on {1} at {2}.format(product,date,time) |
| 3 |  B   |   yy    | 04/10 | 4pm  |   2         | Item {0} was purchased on {1}.format(product,date) |
| 4 |  B   |   yy    | 04/10 | 4pm  |   1         | Product {0} was sold on {1} at {2}.format(product,date,time) |
```

Different 'type' are mapped to a combination of different template_id. Each template id has a distinct template.

Output I am interested in :

```
|ID | type | product | date  | time | template_id | text_col                            |
| 1 |  A   |   xx    | 04/01 | 4pm  |   1         | Product xx was sold on 04/01 at 4pm |
| 2 |  A   |   xx    | 05/01 | 6pm  |   1         | Product xx was sold on 05/01 at 6pm |
| 3 |  B   |   yy    | 04/10 | 4pm  |   2         | Item yy was purchased on 04/10        |
| 4 |  B   |   yy    | 04/10 | 4pm  |   1         | Product yy was sold on 04/10 at 4pm |
```

I tried iterating over every row in the df and storing the product, date, time varibales like this :

```
 for x in df.iterrows(): 
     product=product
     date=date
     time=time
```

But i am not sure how to embed these values in the template column and then output these values as a new column for this df.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
# Store templates in a dict
templates = {
    1: "Product {0} was sold on {1} at {2}",
    2: "Item {0} was purchased on {1}",
}
# Create a list of strings with desired values
text_col = [
    templates[row["template_id"]]
    .replace("{0}", row["product"])
    .replace("{1}", row["date"])
    .replace("{2}", row["time"])
    for _, row in df.iterrows()
]
# Add a new column
df["text_col"] = pd.DataFrame(text_col)

print(df)
  product   date time  template_id                             text_col
0      xx  04/01  4pm            1  Product xx was sold on 04/01 at 4pm
1      xx  05/01  6pm            1  Product xx was sold on 05/01 at 6pm
2      yy  04/10  4pm            2       Item yy was purchased on 04/10
3      yy  04/10  4pm            1  Product yy was sold on 04/10 at 4pm
```